# How to change the max limit of the attribute according to the unit?

Tags: magento2, form-validation

I have a unit **length** that accept entering **cm, inch and ft**. I know how to set-up the input validation in one limit. Let say, I want to have max limit to **100cm**. I can set the field validation to the following:

```
<input name="length" type="text" data-validate="{required:true, max:100}" />
```

And let say, I have a select field that contain the unit of **length**:

```
<select name="unit">
    <option value="cm">cm</option>
    <option value="inch">inch</option>
    <option value="ft">ft</option>
</select>
```

The problem is: If I enter **100ft** or **100inch**,  the validation still pass. How can I adjust the `max` value when I switch the unit? So that **100ft** or **100inch** cannot pass the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's just the matter of JS. First of all, modify the select list a bit:

```
<select name="unit">
    <option value="cm" data-conversion="0.03280840">cm</option>
    <option value="inch"data-conversion="0.08333333">inch</option>
    <option value="ft" data-conversion="1.00000000">ft</option>
</select>
```

Then, write the following JS. You can load it right under the select list, or via requirejs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage'
    ], function($){
        //Change the value depends on the size unit        
        $("select[name='unit']").change(function () {
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
            curr_price = selected.data("conversion");
            curr_max = $('input[name="length]"').rules("max");
            cm_price = $('option[value=cm]').data("price");
            new_max_range = curr_max * cm_price / curr_price;
            $('input[name="length]"').rules("remove", "max");
            $('input[name="productoptions[<?php echo $option->getOptionCode() ?>]"').rules("add", {
                    max: new_max_range
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I just solved it long time ago, but forgot to answer it till now.

Comment: Which File ?? I Will Chnage attribute value inch to semi .

Comment: I forgot the exact file. Just remember on category product page